# Marmalade SDK: is there a way to skip/seek to a part of a video in s3e video play?

Tags: marmalade

I am currently using s3eVideo in the Marmalade SDK to play a video in my project after a button event. I attempted to find a way to implement a slider bar (or something of the like) to go back and forth in the video. I am unsure if this feature is even supported, but I may be wrong. Otherwise, is there a way to open a native video player outside of the app and then play the video that way with the seek feature I need?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way of finding out the length of the video but s3eVideoSetInt (S3E_VIDEO_POSITION, timeInMilliseconds) should do the trick.

I guess it will depend on if the frame index in the file is ok and if the specific platform supports it. Only really did play/stop video in Marmalade so you may have to try using this function while playing, while pause etc and see what works and what errors.